# Custom button as leftBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem

I'm using this code to display a custom button as leftButtonItem:

```
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Back"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector (DetailExperienceTVC.back), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.setTitle(DataManager.shared.arrayMenuTop[DataManager.shared.indexTitle].title, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = ColorManager.shared.generalFont30

    button.sizeToFit()

    button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake((self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height) / 4, 10, 0, 0)

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

but this is what I get [wrong size button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E68uO.png), my question is how can I distanziate the text from the image without cropping it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try calling `sizeToFit` after setting the edge insets?

Comment: @rmaddy yes it does not solve the problem

Comment: Try using size to fit property on button.titleLabel and set minimumfontsize

Comment: @shubham no, it doesn't work

Comment: You need to set the frame of  button

Answer (score -1):

Here's the fix:

```
 button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```